# Expand collapse icons not shown in react-big-scheduler / React-big-scheduler support for antd v4 version

Tags: reactjs, scheduler, antd, timeline, ant-design-pro

I am using react-big-scheduler for timeline view in my project but expand/collapse icons are not displayed. Might be the problem with antd version 4 only. My view is very much similar to https://stephenchou1017.github.io/scheduler/#/ . As you can see Resource0, Resource1, Resource2 have expand collapse icon. These icons are missing.

Any idea or workaround for this?

P.S I am open to other free timeline view libraries if you can suggest some.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: After digging in I got to know that antd v4 uses different icons library the version < 4.
react-big-scheduler uses version<4 that is why icons were not displayed. 
I found there is an open github issue as well for it. https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler/issues/205